# SQL Server 2008 - How to find top 10 tables and order them

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have the following script:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @columnName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @NotCursor TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                    TableName SYSNAME,
                    ColumnName SYSNAME)
DECLARE @StartLoop INT
DECLARE @EndLoop INT
DECLARE @SQLFinalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @NotCursor
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
      COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
(DATA_TYPE = 'date'
OR DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
AND table_name NOT LIKE '%[_]%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

SELECT @StartLoop = MIN(ID),
      @EndLoop = MAX(ID)
FROM @NotCursor

SET @SQLFinalQuery = ';WITH cte_Resultset AS'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'('

WHILE @StartLoop <= @EndLoop
    BEGIN
       SELECT @tableName = TableName,
            @columnName = ColumnName
       FROM @NotCursor
       WHERE  ID = @StartLoop

       SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @tableName + ''' as [TableName], ' + '''' + @columnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' + 'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [NumberofRows]'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
       +'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) 
       +'GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')';
       SET @SQLFinalQuery = @SQLFinalQuery+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+@sql;

       SET @SQLFinalQuery =   CASE 
                             WHEN @StartLoop = @EndLoop THEN @SQLFinalQuery+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+')'
                             ELSE @SQLFinalQuery+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'UNION ALL' 
                          END

       SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1

    END
SET @SQLFinalQuery = @SQLFinalQuery +'SELECT TOP 10 SUM(NumberofRows) AS NumberOfRows,TableName,ColumnName,Year'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'FROM cte_Resultset'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'WHERE Year IS NOT NULL'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) 
+'GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, Year'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'ORDER BY SUM(NumberofRows) DESC'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

EXEC (@SQLFinalQuery)
```

The output of this script provides me with the NumberofRows, TableName, ColumnName, and Year.

However, I also want to additionally filter the results. Currently, the script searches through every table without "_" in it. But, I also want it to also only look at the tables which are related to a calendar (the table must be joint to a calendar). The table where the table name and calendar name can be found is called TimeDependencies. Is there any way to join my current code and this table, so that the result of the script will filter out tables which dont have an associated calendar with them?

Thanks.

Sample Data:

```
T002    dtCodeObjective
T002    dtDCNandPersistency
T002    dtServiceFee
T004    dtMilitaryCommission
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it have to be via code, or can you not use the `Disk Usage by Table` report built into SSMS?

Comment: I would prefer it through code, as when I run the script I would like to be able to see the top 10 tables shown in the results windows of SQL Server. Just so it is able to be used by multiple people.

Comment: So I get it that the column name is not important in the final results.

Comment: What a bizarre requirement. Not really sure what this is doing but it seems like you are trying to get the first 10 datetime columns from any table? And why are you using a cursor for this?

Comment: No It is not I just added it there to see what rows pertained to which column, but no its not important

Comment: What I would like to do is create a script that will return the number rows per year for all dates columns from all the tables in the database.
For example, if we have transactional tableX with N columns , so I need dynamic script which will loop through all columns in a table and find columns with DATE or DATETIME data type. After that it will run through the list of date type columns and return the number of rows per YEAR(with name ex.ColumnDate)

Comment: So if you want the Year, you need the column name. Am I right?

Comment: Yes cause the year comes from the column name

Comment: What columns do you have in TimeDependencies. What is the name of the column with the data and what datatype is it. Also can I get a sample of the data from that column please?

Comment: I have TimeID and TableName in TimeDependencies. TimeID is the name for the column with the Calendars. And the names are just T001, T002, T003, so I would say its just characters.

The sample of the data I will update in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3712641,This answer is related to the question from [SQL Server 2008 - Optimizing Select statement [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998798/sql-server-2008-optimizing-select-statement)

By the time I could answer, the original thread was closed as a duplicate. However as I had already put some time into optimize this query, I am going ahead and adding to this post instead.

What I did is remove looped inserts and eliminated cursors. Tests on local machine showed some performance increment. Please try and let me know if it works for you.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @columnName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @NotCursor TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                    TableName SYSNAME,
                    ColumnName SYSNAME)
DECLARE @StartLoop INT
DECLARE @EndLoop INT
DECLARE @SQLFinalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @NotCursor
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
      COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
(DATA_TYPE = 'date'
OR DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
AND table_name NOT LIKE '%[_]%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

SELECT @StartLoop = MIN(ID),
      @EndLoop = MAX(ID)
FROM @NotCursor

SET @SQLFinalQuery = ';WITH cte_Resultset AS'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'('

WHILE @StartLoop <= @EndLoop
    BEGIN
       SELECT @tableName = TableName,
            @columnName = ColumnName
       FROM @NotCursor
       WHERE  ID = @StartLoop

       SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @tableName + ''' as [TableName], ' + '''' + @columnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' + 'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [NumberofRows]'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
       +'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) 
       +'GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')';
       SET @SQLFinalQuery = @SQLFinalQuery+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+@sql;

       SET @SQLFinalQuery =   CASE 
                             WHEN @StartLoop = @EndLoop THEN @SQLFinalQuery+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+')'
                             ELSE @SQLFinalQuery+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'UNION ALL' 
                          END

       SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1

    END
SET @SQLFinalQuery = @SQLFinalQuery +'SELECT TOP 10 SUM(NumberofRows) AS NumberOfRows,TableName,Year'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'FROM cte_Resultset'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'GROUP BY TableName, Year'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'ORDER BY SUM(NumberofRows) DESC'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

EXEC (@SQLFinalQuery)
```

IF you need to include Columns, Please replace the last 6 line with this

```
SET @SQLFinalQuery = @SQLFinalQuery +'SELECT TOP 10 SUM(NumberofRows) AS NumberOfRows,TableName,ColumnName,Year'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'FROM cte_Resultset'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, Year'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+'ORDER BY SUM(NumberofRows) DESC'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

EXEC (@SQLFinalQuery)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! It does seem to be working better, and is giving the same information as before. Looks good, thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad it was of use to you.

Comment: Hi I updated my questions, I forgot I would also like to have column name in the output, but can't seem to get it working, could you possibly help with this?

Comment: @user3712641, I have added Column to the result set as requested.

Comment: Works perfectly, again can't thank you enough. I guess when I was trying to modify it on the code I had it was much harder, but it was much easier using the code you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58218/discussion-between-gouri-shankar-aechoor-and-user3712641).

Answer (score 1):

Just gather the results inside a table variable and select from that table:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000);
DECLARE @tableName sysname; 
DECLARE @columnName sysname;
DECLARE @count int;
DECLARE theCursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  (DATA_TYPE = 'date' or DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
  and table_name not like '%[_]%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 

OPEN theCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;

DECLARE @tables TABLE (TableName nvarchar(128), ColumnName nvarchar(128), 
                Year int, NumberofRows int)
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @tableName + ''' as [TabelName], ' + 
             '''' + @columnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' +
             'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + 
             ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [NumberofRows] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
             ' GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')';
  PRINT @sql;
  INSERT INTO @tables
  EXEC (@sql);

  FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;
END

SELECT TOP 10 SUM(NumberofRows) NumberOfRows, tableName, Year FROM @tables GROUP BY TableName, Year ORDER BY SUM(NumberofRows) DESC
CLOSE theCursor
DEALLOCATE theCursor;
```

Comment: This seems to work beautifully, presented in a very clean manner as well. Great thank you!

Comment: I don't like the cursor approach here at all but if you do you should add a counter inside so that you can exit the loop once the table variable has 10 rows. Otherwise you just keep running sql that will be ignored by the final query. I will put together a more set based approach that will do the same thing with no cursor.

Comment: Add something like this before the Cursor. declare @ RowCountMax int = 1. Then modify the While with a second condition (and @ RowCountMax < 10). Finally add this right after executing the dynamic sql (set @ RowCountMax = @@ROWCOUNT). That will at least force the loop to exit after it gets 10 rows.

Comment: OK Sean, but we don't know the top 10 tables unless we iterate through all of them and count the matching rows. Your suggestion makes the code return just the 10 top tables ordered by their name.

Comment: Right you start with the top 10 tables, no point getting any more than that. Then limit the rowcount to 10 in the loop since that is all you are going to select anyway.

Comment: What if 11th table contains a number of rows greater than all the first 10?

Comment: Good point. Looking at the comments from the OP they now state they want all rows from all tables anyway. :)

Comment: Anyways I appreciate your participation :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated comments that the OP wants to get the counts for all tables, not just the 10 largest counts this can be done with no loops.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

select @SQL = 
STUFF((
select top 20 'SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' as [TableName], ' + 
             '''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' +
             'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + 
             ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [NumberofRows] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + 
             ' GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ') union all '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  (DATA_TYPE = 'date' or DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
  and table_name not like '%[_]%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 
for xml path('')),1 , 0 , '')

select @SQL = stuff(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 9, 10, '') + ' order by NumberOfRows desc'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```